# Read data from extended table in a template

Tags: twig, shopware

I have a question about shopware 6.
I have created an extra table for my property_group options, called property_group_extension.
So I have extended this table in my theme:

```
class PropertyGroupExtension extends EntityExtension
{
    public function extendFields(FieldCollection $collection): void
    {
        $collection->add(
            new OneToOneAssociationField('property_group_extension', 'id', 'property_group_id', PropertyGroupExtensionDefinition::class, true)
        );
    }

    public function getDefinitionClass(): string
    {
        return PropertyGroupDefinition::class;
    }
}
```

But how can I call this extra db-table `property_group_extension` (with a column **test**) in my twig template?
This is NOT working:

```
properties.html.twig:
{% for group in page.product.sortedProperties %}
    {% block page_product_detail_properties_table_row %}
        <tr class="properties-row">
            {% block page_product_detail_properties_item_label %}
                <th class="properties-label">
                    {{ group.test }} - {# <= HOW CAN I INSERT HERE MY TEST COLUMN??? #}
                    {{ group.translated.name|e }}:
                </th>
            {% endblock %}
            {% block page_product_detail_properties_item_value %}
                <td class="properties-value">
                    {% apply spaceless %}
                        {% for option in group.options %}
                            {% set i = ( i | default(0) ) + 1 %}
                            <span>{% if i > 1 %}, {% endif %}{{ option.translated.name|e }}</span>
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% endapply %}
                </td>
            {% endblock %}
        </tr>
    {% endblock %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: There is no need to add tags in the title of your questions

Comment: Did you check with `dump()`in the twig template if the data is available anywhere? otherwise check my answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

I believe, the data does not automatically populate to the data structures in the `twig` by adding an extension.

You usually would hook into an even that is triggered for the page you want to access the data in.

Next you add an extension to the result so it is accessible in the twig template.